# How to implement gridlayout with multiple padding?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I need to implement a list like on the picture below.

[image]

There are some elements, stroked by different colors:

BLACK - a recyclerview with GridLayoutManager
BLUE - items of the recyclerview

Also there are colored lines meaning a distance between elements. Lines of same length are equals.Green lines are shorter than pink

Main problem is: how to add pink distances to elements 1-6 and make a 7th element aligned to recyclerview's borders?

Comment: Question is unclear

Comment: What exactly is unclear?

Comment: pink line margin you can achieve using grid layout item margin.

Comment: Yes, but how add this margins to specific type of list's elements? I have a two different as you can see.

Comment: If you have three items per row - first row, last row and side items of each row will have the pink line.Basically your code will be in onBindViewHolder and depending on the position,you can hide/show line for each item or use different layouts for each item.